# batch file help required for making a text file

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, dos

I need a batch file to read through the content of a text file and to make a new text file

**my_file.txt**

```
loc name="UAE"     place=DUBAI
loc name="US"      place=NY
loc name="INDIA"   place=DELHI
```

I have a one text file with location names and state like below

**location.txt**

```
US      NY
UAE     DUBAI
INDIA   DELHI
```

This `location.txt` has many rows, above is just an example.

Kindly provide a batch script which should read `location.txt` and make a text file like `my_file.txt`.

Comment: You have not asked a question about programming. You have asked someone to do your work. Also, you haven't specified if your location.txt is fixed width or delimited. What if the country is "South Korea" and the city is "Seoul"? How would the program know that Korea is part of the country and not the city?

Comment: @dbenham sorry, location.txt has single space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in (my_file.txt) do (
echo loc name=%%a place=%%b >>my_file_new.txt
)
```